# How to get started with OpenCV 2.4.2 in ubuntu 10.4?

Tags: opencv, build, build-process, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to install latest OpenCV version 2.4.2 on a linux (ubuntu 10.4) PC.

I downloaded the tar ball.
Un-tar-ed it.
And followed [install opencv in ubuntu 10.04](http://helpforlinux.blogspot.in/2010/07/install-opencv-in-ubuntu-1004.html).

While 'Make' I got error after "**`Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core`**" comes in red color here; after millions of warning or error msgs it shows as follows:

```
... ... ...
../../lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.2: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string()'
../../lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.2: undefined reference to `typeinfo for int'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Keyword: "Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core" with quotes.

I googled for it and found that the PC needs CUDA driver. For now I don't need that perhaps.

Does that driver installation required here or I can bypass that particular 'make' process?

My aim is to get started with OpenCV as soon as possible in ubuntu. Does these build processes required for compiling own cpp file using openCV 2.4.2 libraries? I am not concentrating on static or non static libraries.

Has anyone worked on for ubuntu as just like on windows I install OpenCV and get started just by setting path to the include file and keeping .dlls with the custom executable file, say for capturing images from a camera.

<=== Update ===>

Followed http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html.

It passed the Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core.

now it stucks at **`Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_highgui`** with following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.a(cap_libv4l.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'v4l2_close'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'v4l2_close' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libv4l2.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libv4l2.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_highgui] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Seems the **cmake** parameters has to be studied well. Any shortcut will be helpful.

Comment: +1 for Astor for notifying it.

Comment: Good work both of you. \m/ :)

Comment: @Rick2047 Seriously, review your questions and accept the answers that solved them. I'm sure you know how.

Comment: You were following some very old install instructions. The instructions in the link you posted after the updated question should work fine. About that error that you still have, do you have v4l installed in your ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I have installed OpenCV 2.4.2 and written a script to install it. You can find it here https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/2.4/opencv2_4_2.sh

Or checkout my blog post for more detailed instructions. http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/install-opencv-2-4-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

```
echo "Installing OpenCV 2.4.2"
mkdir OpenCV
cd OpenCV
echo "Removing any pre-installed ffmpeg and x264"
sudo apt-get remove remove ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev
echo "Installing Dependenices"
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy
sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libgtk2.0-dev
echo "Downloading ffmpeg"
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.11.1.tar.bz2
echo "Installing ffmpeg"
tar -xvf ffmpeg-0.11.1.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg-0.11.1/
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
make
sudo make install
cd ..
echo "Downloading v4l"
wget http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-utils/v4l-utils-0.8.8.tar.bz2
echo "Installing v4l"
tar -xvf v4l-utils-0.8.8.tar.bz2
cd v4l-utils-0.8.8/
make
sudo make install
cd ..
echo "Downloading OpenCV 2.4.2"
wget -O OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.2/OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2/download
echo "Installing OpenCV 2.4.2"
tar -xvf OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..
make
sudo make install
sudo echo “/usr/local/lib” >> /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig
echo "OpenCV 2.4.2 ready to be used"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that problem is related to CUDA, but you can disable it when configuring cmake, passing `WITH_CUDA=OFF`:

```
cd OpenCV-2.4.2
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_CUDA=OFF ..
make 
sudo make install
```

Another interesting flag for you might be `BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON`

**EDIT**:

[Apparently OpenCV 2.4.2 needs to use a more recent CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470336/176769), so go ahead and install CMake 2.8.8 in your system.

Comment: Outputs as:

'ele@rick:~/OpenCV_svn/opencv/release$ make

[ 13%] Built target opencv_highgui
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core

... million error of warning msgs

../../lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string()'
../../lib/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to [typeinfo for int]
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2'

Comment: Updated answer. I think you might need to update CMake to v2.8.8.

Comment: Yeah I had cmake version 2.8.0. I tried to update it. It says as below:
'ele@rick:~/cmake-2.8.8$ make
Linking CXX executable cmIML_test
CMakeFiles/cmIML_test.dir/test_ABI_CXX.cxx.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to __gxx_personality_v0'
CMakeFiles/cmIML_test.dir/test_INT_CXX.cxx.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to __gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Utilities/KWIML/test/cmIML_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/KWIML/test/CMakeFiles/cmIML_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2' It seems I forgot everything of linux. :P

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by going to CMakeCache.txt after generating UNIX makefile using cmake-gui, in the directory you set to build the binaries, and adding the path for the `libcuda.so` to this line `CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=` so in my case i ended up with `CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/libcuda.so`

If you are not going to use your CUDA toolkit you can disable this settings when you cmake your opencv with CUDA=off

Comment: It is very unlikely that the error (see question updated) is related to CUDA.